# Insering multiple row values with date using single statement into oracle11g database

Tags: database, oracle

I have written the query from inserting multiple rows values in single statement. when I inserting the date it shows '01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"'. Please find the query here with

```
  INSERT ALL 
INTO SUPP (ACC_NO,S_NAME,PRICE,DOS) VALUES (3010,'MARIA_CURIE',130,to_date('2011103','YYYYMMDD'))
INTO SUPP (ACC_NO,S_NAME,PRICE,DOS) VALUES (4010,'GALILO_GALILE',180,to_date('20121116','YYYYMMMDD'))
INTO SUPP (ACC_NO,S_NAME,PRICE,DOS)  VALUES (5010,'BLAISE_PASCAL',101,to_date('2010101','YYYYMMDD')) 
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

but when I inserted one at a time its executing perfectly  sample as below

```
   INSERT ALL 
INTO SUPP (ACC_NO,S_NAME,PRICE,DOS) VALUES (3010,'MARIA_CURIE',130,to_date('2011103','YYYYMMDD'))
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the date format of second insert, there is an extra m in the date format... Try this:

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO SUPP (ACC_NO,S_NAME,PRICE,DOS) VALUES (3010,'MARIA_CURIE',130,to_date('2011103','YYYYMMDD'))
INTO SUPP (ACC_NO,S_NAME,PRICE,DOS) VALUES (4010,'GALILO_GALILE',180,to_date('20121116','YYYYMMDD'))
INTO SUPP (ACC_NO,S_NAME,PRICE,DOS)  VALUES (5010,'BLAISE_PASCAL',101,to_date('2010101','YYYYMMDD')) 
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```